# How can I loop through an IP address range in python

Tags: python

How can I loop through an IP address range in python? Lets say I want to loop through every IP from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168. How can this be done?

Comment: is `192.168.` a valid ip address?

Comment: have a look at the [IPy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/IPy) library

Answer (score 26):

If you want to loop through a network you can define a network using ipaddress module. Such as ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.1.0/24')

```
import ipaddress
for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.1.0/24'):
    print(ip)
```

This will produce a result like this:

```
192.168.1.0
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
...
192.168.1.255
```

But if you want to iterate through a range of ip's, you might need to convert between ip and integer.

```
>>> int(ipaddress.IPv4Address('10.0.0.1'))
167772161
```

So:

```
start_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address('10.0.0.1')
end_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address('10.0.0.5')
for ip_int in range(int(start_ip), int(end_ip)):
    print(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip_int))
```

will produce a result like:

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
10.0.0.4
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
for i,j in product(range(256),range(256)):
    print "192.168.{0}.{1}".format(i,j)
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try, you know, looping with `range`?

```
for i in range(256):
    for j in range(256):
        ip = "192.168.%d.%d" % (i, j)
        print ip
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from netaddr import *
ip = IPNetwork('192.0.2.16/29')
>>> ip_list = list(ip)
>>> len(ip_list)
8
>>> ip_list
[IPAddress('192.0.2.16'), IPAddress('192.0.2.17'), ..., IPAddress('192.0.2.22'), IPAddress('192.0.2.23')]
```

Comment: Hi Petr - your answer would be better if you could include some explanation of how or why your code would solve the questioner's problem.

Comment: Hi Petr, thanks for this solution, it was exactly what I was looking for as I am already using netaddr and I don't want to import another lib

Answer (score 2):

Using netaddr module:
http://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#netaddr.IPSet.iter_ipranges

```
from netaddr import iter_iprange
generator = iter_iprange('192.168.1.1', '192.168.255.255', step=1)
generator.next() # 192.168.1.1
generator.next() # 192.168.1.2
```

Comment: link is broken.