# Python help to take in a range of IP addresses from a text file and then output each ip address in the range

Tags: python, linux, parsing

So far the program takes in all the text files in a directory and then outputs them to a file with the same name but .out. If there is an ip address `1992.168.1.1-192.168.1.7` I want it to output all of the ips in that range to the new file name.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re
import os

try:
    if file.endswith (".txt"):
    f=open(file, 'r')
try:
    file = open(f, "r")
    ips = []
    for text in file.readlines():
       regex = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})',text)
       if regex is not None and regex not in ips:
           ips.append(regex)

    for ip in ips:
        #name of the file
        name = os.path.splitext() [0]
        name = name +".out"
       outfile = open(name, 'w')
       spider = "".join(ip)
       if spider is not '':
          outfile.write(spider)
          outfile.write("\n")
finally:
    file.close()
    outfile.close()
except IOError, (errno, strerror):
    print "I/O Error(%s) : %s" % (errno, strerror)
```

Comment: what does you input file look like and are you using subnet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I loop through an IP address range in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368659/how-can-i-loop-through-an-ip-address-range-in-python)

Comment: i would recommend the first thing you do is get netaddr package then doing ip ranges and really any networking calculations will be trivial

Comment: One of your problems could be that you're opening the file in write mode multiple times.

Comment: And with the file opens, with open is a nice thing to have.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.3+, use the [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress.html#iteration) module:

```
>>> for addr in IPv4Network('192.0.2.0/28'):
...   addr
...
IPv4Address('192.0.2.0')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.1')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.2')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.3')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.4')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.5')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.6')
...
IPv4Address('192.0.2.15')
```

Comment: I think judging from the OP's print statement we can assume he/she is not using python 3

Comment: Yes, but I'm always happy to plug a standard useful module ;)

Comment: well since we are plugging  I imagine `https://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/wiki/Using3144`  would be pretty useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to parse the ip into an integer - if you want to roll your own, that is.

```
def ip_to_int(ipstr):
    b = [ int(p) for p in ipstr.split('.') ]
    return (b[0] << 24) + (b[1] << 16) + (b[2] << 8) + b[3]

def int_to_ip(i):
    octets = []
    for n in range(4):
        octets.append(i & 0xff)
        i >>= 8
    return ".".join([ str(octet) for octet in octets[::-1]])

def iprange(ipstring):
    ipstart, ipend = ipstring.split('-')
    return [ int_to_ip(ipint) for ipint in range(ip_to_int(ipstart), ip_to_int(ipend)+1) ]
```

And this really does not understand anything about valid addresses (network addresses), nor has it any error checking.